# Not getting GUI mode on ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition after installation on vmware workstation 7

Tags: gui, vmware

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition on my PC using VMWare workstation 7.
I assigned 1GB RAM and 20 GB Hard disk to Ubuntu.

While starting Ubuntu virtual machine, It is not starting up with GUI mode. In is prompting me my Login ID in textual mode always. After waiting for long time as well the GUI mode is not appearing.

I tried running 
sudo apt-get install updates
sudo apt-get install xinit
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

Honestly, i don't know the meaning of all these.I am very new to ubuntu.Please help me here what to do?

Below is my Laptop configuration
OS: Genuine Windows 7 Home Basic(64 bit)
RAM: 3 GB
Processor: Intel core i3

Regards
Salil

Comment: Please post the logs from `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: <code>sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start</code> worked for me

Answer (score 10):

You may try `sudo lightdm`, `startx`, `sudo startx`, or `sudo gdm` in that order of preference(Use the first that works). You may then try to set it up as the last entry in the system-wide `crontab`(See http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg28t5.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Today I installed the 12.04 version and found the same problem as no GUI was seen.
But after running the command "startx"I got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Caution !

After installing Ubuntu under Vmware xx be sure that the vmware tools 
are installed as well, you should receive a message from Ubuntu to explain
that but in some case not, so be patient.

Otherwise, startx work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new to posting: using VMWare 4.1 with Ubuntu 12.04 as VM or Guest. Graphics not working as expected after finding that this was a common problem. Was able to login through defaulted shell. Ran the following command `sudo lighdm` System started right up. Long story short, open terminal and edit your system wide crontab.

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

After last hash-tag enter and save the following line.

```
@reboot root lightdm
```

After several reboots, system seems to have no problems. And hopefully never will. Can't say for sure that this is the best solution...